# Picking random 100 files in aws s3 path with subdirectories and then copying them to another folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a aws s3 bucket `s3://bucket1/` that has multiple subdirectories at two levels with the structure
`s3://bucket1/shard-*/task-*/filename1.txt` and I have to select random 100 files from the bucket. What I did was to use `"aws s3 ls recursive"` along with awk and shuf to get a list of these 100 files and store it in a file.
But now I wanted to copy these 100 files into a specific bucket in s3. How do I go about doing this? Is there a "aws s3 cp" where I can use the list?

Comment: can't use list with `aws s3 cp`. loop and copy them.

Comment: You could use `s3 sync` with `--exclude="*"` and a bunch of `--include="file1"` params.  Though, I suspect it'd be quicker, and easier, to just loop through many `s3 cp` commands.

Comment: It would be much simpler to do this from a program, such as a Python script. Do you have any preferred programming language?